# XSLT copy groups per chunks and keep children nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

im trying to achieve this:
I have this input file

```
<Message>
   <Cons>
      <TratEqnt>
         <sqNumberFinal>1</sqNumberFinal>
         <numberOfSls>104</numberOfSls>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>1</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831581</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>2</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831582</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>3</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831583</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>4</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831584</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>5</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831585</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>6</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831586</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>7</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831587</id>
         </Sl>
      </TratEqnt>
      <TratEqnt>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>1</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831581</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>2</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831582</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>3</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831583</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>4</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831584</id>
         </Sl>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>5</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831585</id>
         </Sl>
         <Goods>
            <seq>1</seq>
            <dec>1</dec>
         </Goods>
      </TratEqnt>
   </Cons>
</Message>
```

and what i want to achieve is that if in every `TratEqnt` group the number `Sl`is greater than 4 for example 12 then i should create others `TratEqnt` with chunks of 4 `SL` until there are no `<Sl>` left. It is important that each  `TratEqnt` must has the children nodes. To be more specific my output for the given message must be this:

```
<Message>
   <Cons>
        <TratEqnt>
             <sqNumberFinal>1</sqNumberFinal>
             <numberOfSls>104</numberOfSls>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>1</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831581</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>2</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831582</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>3</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831583</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>4</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831584</id>
             </Sl>
         </TratEqnt>
         <TratEqnt>
             <sqNumberFinal>1</sqNumberFinal>
             <numberOfSls>104</numberOfSls>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>5</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831585</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>6</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831586</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>7</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831587</id>
             </Sl>
        </TratEqnt>
        <TratEqnt>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>1</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831581</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>2</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831582</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>3</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831583</id>
             </Sl>
             <Sl>
                <sqNumber>4</sqNumber>
                <id>D36831584</id>
             </Sl>
         </TratEqnt>
         <TratEqnt>
         <Sl>
            <sqNumber>5</sqNumber>
            <id>D36831585</id>
         </Sl>
        </TratEqnt>
   </Cons>
</Message>
```

My code is this but it is not working properly

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
expand-text="yes">

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="TratEqnt">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Sl" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 4">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to change

```
<xsl:template match="TratEqnt">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Sl" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 4">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="TratEqnt">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Sl" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 4">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or probably rather

```
<xsl:template match="TratEqnt">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Sl" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 4">
           <xsl:copy select="..">
             <xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>

             <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Copying the outer nodes could be done with XSLT 3 by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

Comment: thanks for your ultra quick response but this is now drawing the TratEqnt with the SL in chunks of 4 as desired. It only draws one TratEqnt

Comment: @rammale91, see the edit, I think that bug you complain about was in your code.

Comment: maybe  match="TratEqnt" is not true and i must go to the parent level

Comment: If i have other data groups under TratEqnt i think that <xsl:copy select=".."> will not copy them. Am i right?

Comment: You seem to want a new result element named `TratEqnt` for each group the `xsl:for-each-group` creates, that is what I used the `<xsl:copy-of select="..">` for. Its children are copied by the `<xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>`.

Comment: thank you! Check the updated question though. I;ve added the Goods in the second TratEqnt. This code runs fine except that it prints 1 and 1 for the last TratEqnt

Comment: @rammale91, don't expect answer to work if you change the input data.

Comment: haha agree! Thanks! You are lightning speed fast and prolific : )

Comment: One more question..because im using xslt 2.0  <xsl:copy-of select=".."> is not working but i cannot find the relevant expression for this